# Using raw c style matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen3

Is there an easy way to wrap a `double**` in a c++ Eigen typ so that it can be used in Eigen expressions? As far as I know, the `Eigen::Map` class only supports `double*`. The storage where `double**` points to is not guaranteed to be continuous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map a Eigen Matrix to an C array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535399/map-a-eigen-matrix-to-an-c-array)

Comment: [Convert Eigen Matrix to C array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8443102/995714)

Comment: As stated in my question I want to wrap a C matrix not a C array. The two links only show the usage of `Eigen::Map` with a C array. The storage where the `double**` points to is not guaranteed to be continuous.

Comment: there's no matrix type in C. If you create it your own so you have to work with them manually

Comment: @Jodebo `double**` is not a matrix, assuming array decay, it's an array of arrays at best. It doesn't guarantee rectangular size, which is pretty important for a matrix, that's a bigger problem IMO.

Comment: @luk32 That's true but I know that the shape is rectangular. I want to use it with `ceres::DynamicAutoDiffCostFunction` [Link](http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_modeling.html#dynamicautodiffcostfunction) and the interface of the cost functor is `T const* const*`.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, you can use an `Eigen::Map` to wrap contiguous data:

```
double *data = new...
Map<MatrixXd> mappedData(data, m, n);
mappedData.transposeInPlace(); // etc.
```

Non-contiguous data has to be made contiguous, either as a [copy in an Eigen object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector/), or as a contiguous `double*` and using a `Map` as above.

#### Edit

You can't use (map/wrap) a non-contiguous section of memory as an Eigen::Matrix. If you have control of the memory allocation, you can do something like:

```
// make contiguous data array; better yet, make an
// Eigen::VectorXd of the same size to ensure alignment
double *actualData = new double[m*n]; 
double **columnPointers = new double[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) columnPointers[i] = actualData + i * m;
... // do whatever you need to do with the double**
Map<MatrixXd> mappedData(actualData, m, n);
... // send to ceres, or whatever
```

Comment: I don't want to copy the data, I would like to wrap it. I want to use it with `ceres::DynamicAutoDiffCostFunction` [Link](http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_modeling.html#dynamicautodiffcostfunction) where copying is probably too expensive.